# Where to save this kind of data?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am developing a website in React that extracts data from packages that users request around the world, I have a searcher that fetch the data from my backend, I want to save the lastest Packages and save it, for the next time that users search for another packages, something like "result of last search" and keep it saved, even if customer navigate to other route, the questions is I dont know where to save, if I have to use, Redux or Local Storage or something else?

Comment: "Pure" client side: use localStorage. "Pure" server side: use your server's session management. "React side": search the web because there's tons of "how to do session management using react+redux" articles out there.

Comment: I'm really not understanding what you mean by "I want to save the lastest Packages and save it". Are you talking modules?  Or browser? Is there any code you can provide?

Comment: localstorage would be the best place to store temporary data that does not matter if it is lost.  If you want to store search terms for a long term, then you need to use a database.

Comment: Sorry, a use case would be that the user access this route package/search and there it will show him the search results, then he would access package/123 to see a specific package, but when returning to package/search it will show him the packages from the search that he did earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the results to be saved over multiple loads of the page, Redux won't be enough, since Redux only saves data in the current running script's memory, which is not persistent.

Local Storage is an option, but it has a relatively low size limit. If you have a lot of data, it may reach the limit quickly and become inoperable.

IndexedDB is like Local Storage, but its size limit is much higher, and it has a more complicated interface. If you have a lot of data, that's what I'd recommend. You may wish to use a library like [localForage](https://github.com/localForage/localForage) to make things easier.

Both IndexedDB and Local Storage save the data to the user's local machine. So, for example, if you want to save data for users regardless of what machine they log on from, or to cache data from different users' requests, the local machine options won't be enough - you'll need to save the data in a database on your server instead.